# Javascript - Show/hide pictures with buttons

Tags: javascript, image, button, hide, show

I would like to improve my script so I can have more buttons which can show one image each. (I need 49 buttons). At the moment I only have two well working buttons. How should I write my script below so I can make 49 buttons?

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function showHide() {
        var ele = document.getElementById("showHideDiv");
        var ele1 = document.getElementById("showHideDiv1");
        ele1.style.display = "none";
        if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";             
          }
        else {
            ele.style.display = "block";            
        }
    }

function showHide1() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("showHideDiv");
    var ele1 = document.getElementById("showHideDiv1");
    ele.style.display = "none";
    if(ele1.style.display == "block") {
            ele1.style.display = "none";
      }
    else {
        ele1.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="return showHide();">box1</button>
<button onclick="return showHide1();">box2</button>
<div id="showHideDiv" style="display:none;"><img  src="1.gif" height="280" width="120"/></div>
<div id="showHideDiv1" style="display:none;"><img  src="2.gif" height="280" width="120"/></div>
```

Comment: Do you want to dynamically add them, or is it ok to just have them in the html?

Answer (score 0):

The showHide() can receive a parameter with the div id.

```
function showHide(my_id) {
    var ele = document.getElementById("showHideDiv" + my_div);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";             
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";            
    }
}
```

What lacks in this code is to hide all the other divs.

Comment: "What lacks in this code is to hide all the other divs." - use classes instead of ids. Each time just hide all divs with this class and show only one that is needed.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're meaning. Do you mind rewriting the script and adding one button + one picture so I can see the result?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin I agree, this is a possible approach. Or, all the divs can be inside a parent div, and then the script can hide all of this div's childs (without the need to put a class in each div). The best approach will depend on the original markup.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is another approach, using jQuery (I know, I know, but I just can't make it work on pure javascript). I've used the following markup:

```
<div id="template">
    <button class="toggleButton"></button>
    <div class="showHideDiv"><img src="" height="280" width="120"/></div>
</div>
<div id="main">
</div>
```

Div `template` is used as template for other divs. Here is javascript code:

```
var main = $('#main');
// copy template to make 49 images.
var template = $('#template');
for (var i= 0; i < 49; i++) {
    var div = template.clone();
    var img = main.find('img');
    var button = div.find('button');
    img.attr('src', i + '.gif');
    button.text('box'+(i+1));   
    main.append(div.html());    
}
// add toggle event handler
$(document).on("click", ".toggleButton", function(e) {
    $('.showHideDiv').hide();
    $(e.target).next('.showHideDiv').show();
});
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/69Sp9/1/). It has a lot of errors in console, since there are no real images there, but that should be ok in real application.